# Calling a custom emacs function with arguments

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp

I've got this function in my .bash_rc:

`function ForwardSearchXdvi {`
`latex -src *.tex;`
    `for i in *.dvi; do xdvi -sourceposition "$1 ${i/.dvi/.tex}" $i; done ;`
`}`

it works... I call it by command line with the $1 argument (the target line number in my file.tex) and it's fine.

I'd like to run it directly from emacs so I made this command:

`(defun ForwardXdviSearch ()`
`(interactive)`
  `(shell-command (format "bash -ic %s" (shell-quote-argument "latex -src J[HCI]*.tex; for i in J[HCI]*.dvi; do xdvi -sourceposition \"$1 ${i/.dvi/.tex}\" $i; done ;")))`
`)`

How can I pass the argument $1 to the function when I call it with "M-x Function" ?

Comment: Make sure you read `C-h f interactive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use special form `interactive` for reading arguments.  Something like this untested code:

```
(defun forward-xdvi-search (line-number)
  (interactive "nForward to line: ")
  (shell-command
   (format "bash -ic %s"
           (shell-quote-argument
            (format "latex -src J[HCI]\*.tex; for i in J[HCI]\*.dvi; do xdvi -sourceposition \"%d ${i/.dvi/.tex}\" $i; done ;"
                    line-number)))))
```

Edited with the improvement suggested by @phils

Comment: `interactive` has a code for reading numbers, so you can use `"nForward to line: "`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I obtain: `Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (line) (interactive) (shell-command (format "bash -ic %s" (shell-quote-argument "latex -src J[HCI]*.tex; for i in J[HCI]*.dvi; do xdvi -sourceposition \"$1 ${i/.dvi/.tex}\" $i; done ;")))), 0`

Comment: @phils Right!  I should have read `C-h f interactive` myself :-)  Updated the code with your suggestion.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi, it seems you did not copied the code right, you copied `(interactive)`, instead of `(interactive "nForward to line: ")`, so emacs cannot figure how to read the 1st argument.

Comment: @juanleon, thank you very much for your help but I copied the code right and it doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out how to pass the argument to the function. I tried C-u "number" M-x Function. I tried M-x Function. No way. I'm not a programmer so please, don't blame me.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi with `(interactive "nForward to line: ")` M-x function should do the trick (function should ask you for a number, interactively). I am not sure what is happening in your setup.  By the way, I think you should remove the -i flag to the bash (since it is not an interactive bash).  (and I was no trying to blame anybody :-) )

Comment: Also, I find odd that in your error message there is a $1, while in the function I wrote there is none... please make sure function being called is just the one suggested.

Comment: @juanleon You're right!!! It works! I called the command with the old name! Thank you! I can't vote (i't my first time in here) but you did great!